# Building Unity3d Project reloads SteamVR plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I'm Building my Unity project with a custom script.
The crucial line is the following

```
BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(new string[] {}, path + filename + ".exe",
   BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows,
   BuildOptions.None);
```

If I execute this, Unity will reload the Scene in a way that the SteamVR plugin is reinitialized.
Effectively this Plugin asks me to accept some settings with a dialog every time I build the project.

When I build the Project using the standart Build and Run option (ctrl+B) this does not happen.

Is there a way to prevent this reloading from happening with the BuildPipeline ?

Comment: Since this does not happen when building the Project using the standartd Build and Run option (ctrl+B), does this also not happen with just the Build button?

Comment: I think it did not happen with just build either (unable to try right until the weekend)